# How to execute Roslyn fixers that rely on internal interfaces

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to support built-in Roslyn code fixers in my IDE (QueryStorm). I have had success with some fixers, mostly the ones that don't require a user interface, e.g. `ProjectSymbolReferenceCodeAction` which can add missing `using namespace ...` declarations.

I'm having trouble supporting other fixers due to the **necessary types being internal**. For example, the `CodeActionWithNestedActions` type is internal, so I have to use reflection to get the `NestedCodeActions` if I want to offer them in my IDE. While inconvenient, this is still doable.

However, other situations don't seem to have viable workarounds. For example, the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.GenerateEqualsAndGetHashCodeFromMembers` fixer requires a service called `IPickMembersService` to collect additional information from the user. The problem is that this interface is internal so I can't implement it.

Does this mean I can't use this fixer and others like it or am I going about this the wrong way? If I can't use these fixers, what would be a good way to determine which fixers I can use and which I can't?

Comment: FYI, I've asked ChatGPT "is it possible to dynamically create class which implements interface obtained with reflection?" and he throws at me some code which supposed to solve "The problem is that this interface is internal so I can't implement it" issue. He creates dynamic assembly, add type to it, add interface implementation to the type and implements all methods with ILGenerator.

Comment: Small FYI first: we did recently make [NestedActions](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/763bddbb4dbd281d5f8ae5260e8384d148781ffa) public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean I can't use this fixer and others like it

Those interfaces are internal so we really don't expect third parties to be implementing them. You could file a bug against Roslyn to figure out a plan here, but I admit I'm not sure which direction we'd do. (We've had some similar conversations around VS Code too, since we don't support these fixes in VS Code since our existing UI isn't cross-platform.)

Note that some of those fixes too have options that will show UI, and some that won't. If you're seeing bugs where we're not gracefully detecting the lack of the service and throwing exceptions, do file bugs or send PRs.

> or am I going about this the wrong way?

It's hard to say if you're also doing other wrong things; feel free to open a conversation on GitHub with the issues you're running into, and we can comment on whether that's because you *did* take a wrong path somewhere, or you're just doing something we never anticipated.

Comment: I understand the Visual Studio UI for those fixers isn't cross-platform, but couldn't the UI be implemented separately for different platforms while keeping the rest of the fixer logic? Or is there too little logic in the fixers to justify it? I mean, I *could* just reimplement a particular fixer myself if I needed it, but I just don't see the benefit in making the interface private.

Comment: We'd have to rearchitect how these sorts of fixers work. It's easy for a fixer to display a UI in VS for Windows just by firing up a dialog at the right point in the code. That doesn't work too well in VS Code when the machine running the code fix and the machine with UI might be different machines with VS Code's remote session support, for example.